# C# , pull sites from TXT, pull datafrom website, output data to lists and CSV

Tags: c#, csv

Good morning guys I'm new to this place and have been having a lot of issues getting any of the findings to work.

I'm currently using C# inside visual studio community and was using a you tube video as reference but I'm stuck getting it to work efficiently (i think its in a loop)  and to do other actions. 
Im trying to  get a list of urls from a text file in desktop or by user inputting it to a field:
EG: program opens HE puts IP in one text box and hits submit program runs and iots done. 
or if it pulls a list of IP's from Desktop C: then it will add it to the website while using a loop? 
eg:
my current code is similar to this  as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HTTPcollect_Windows_Form_App
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> IPs = new List<string>();
        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        String html =     web.DownloadString("http://www.ipvoid.com/scan/8.8.8.8/");
        MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"IP Address.*<strong>(.+?)    <\/strong>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
           foreach (Match m in m1)
        {
            string IP = m.Groups[1].Value;
            IPs.Add(IP);

        }
        listBox1.DataSource = IPs;

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

  }
  }
```